# Unconventional rounding of numbers - not all numbers work

Tags: vb.net

I'm adding two decimal numbers. Whenever the fractional part gets to 0.60 it should be rounded up, for example 20.60 is rounded up to 21.00.

I've been able to do that, and the application is mostly working, but whenever the number before the decimal point exceeds the hundreds column, lets say 999.40, and it gets to the thousands column, the thousands separator doesn't work. For example, if I want to add two numbers, say 600.20 and 600.30, instead of my answer being 1,200.50 I get 1.00.

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Calculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Calculate.Click
    'ans for txtbox5.tetx

    Try
        If Convert.ToInt32(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right((Val(Label41.Text).ToString("N2")), 2)) + Convert.ToInt32(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right((Val(Label42.Text).ToString("N2")), 2)) > 99 Then
            MessageBox.Show("invalid entry")
        Else
            Label41.Text = Val(TxtBox2.Text)
            Label42.Text = Val(TxtBox34.Text)

            'sum of numbers in two txtbox
            'TxtBox5.Text = Val(TxtBox2.Text) + Val(TxtBox34.Text)
            Label43.Text = (Val(Label41.Text) + Val(Label42.Text)).ToString("N2")

            'strip last 2 decimals :
            ln = Convert.ToInt32(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right((Val(Label43.Text).ToString("N2")), 2))
            Label44.Text = ln.ToString


            'form decimal from 2 decimals
            Label45.Text = "0." & Label44.Text

            'subtract new decimal from 1st answer
            Label46.Text = (Val(Label43.Text) - Val(Label45.Text)).ToString("N2")

            'checks if striped decimal is btw 100 and 59
            If (Val(Label44.Text)) < 100 And (Val(Label44.Text)) > 59 Then
                runup = runup + 1
                newans = (Val(Label44.Text) - Val(60))
                Label45.Text = (Val(Label45.Text) - Val(0.6)).ToString("N2")

                Try
                    'check if decimal is between 100 and 59
                    If (Val(newans)) < 100 And (Val(newans)) > 59 Then
                        runup = runup + 1
                        newans = (Val(newans) - Val(60))
                        Label45.Text = (Val(Label45.Text) - Val(0.6)).ToString("N2")

                        Label47.Text = (Val(runup) + Val(Label46.Text)) + Val(Label45.Text).ToString("N2")
                        runup = 0

                        'check if new decimal is between 60 and 0
                    ElseIf (Val(newans)) < 60 And (Val(newans)) >= 0 Then
                        Label47.Text = ((Val(runup) + Val(Label46.Text)) + Val(Label45.Text)).ToString("N2")
                        runup = 0
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try

                'check if striped decimal is btw 60 and 0
            ElseIf (Val(Label44.Text)) < 60 And (Val(Label44.Text)) >= 0 Then
                Label47.Text = ((Val(runup) + Val(Label46.Text)) + Val(Label45.Text)).ToString("N2")
                runup = 0
            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    TxtBox5.Text = Label47.Text
```

What is causing the problem with the larger numbers?

Comment: That is a lot of code, and it is not clear where your problem is. It seems to me you could reduce the code to less than 5 lines to illustrate the problem. Could you please do so?

Comment: Ive tried reducing it but it didn't work...the initial problem was to strip the decimal values after the decimal point ".60456" and round it at the 60th mark as in when ever we get to 60 the numbers before the decimal point increases by one, I've been able to do that.

Comment: Now my new problem is if the numbers exceed 999.60, instead of my results being 1000.00 it reads 1.00. Please if you can help try these numbers 600.30 and 600.20

Comment: Please provide code that adds these two numbers (you don't need 60 lines of code to add two numbers), and that illustrates the problem.

Comment: From a design point of view it is better to abstract the code that manipulates the values from all of the GUI code. Write a short function which tries to do what you want and ask your question about that. As an added benefit, once you get it working the code itself will be more readable. Please read this [mcve]

Comment: okay will do that..Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear from your question exactly what you are trying to achieve that can't be done using math.round.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are making your code harder to understand by using UI elements (e.g. labels) as if they were variables. This is not helped by the names of those labels - how are you meant to figure out what, say, "Label44" represents?

You can take the input data from the textboxes and parse that into a suitable data type - I recommend Decimal for this particular case - and using suitable variable names will make it easier to see what the code is doing.

As an example, I put three textboxes on a form and named them "tbNum1", "tbNum2", and "tbSum", added a button named "bnCalculate", and used this code:

```
Private Sub bnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnCalculate.Click
    Dim num1 As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(tbNum1.Text)
    Dim num2 As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(tbNum2.Text)

    Dim sum = num1 + num2
    Dim frac = sum - Math.Floor(sum)

    If frac >= 0.6 Then
        sum = Math.Ceiling(sum)
    End If

    tbSum.Text = sum.ToString("N2")

End Sub
```

The code would need to be modified to work correctly for negative numbers.

I could not discern what some of your code was intended to do, e.g. is the first check intended to restrict the number of decimal places entered? There are cleaner ways to do that.

N.B. Do not use `Try...Catch` with an empty `Catch` part because it will hide problems from you.